# Removing margin from YouTube Livestream page

Tags: css, youtube

I've tried a bunch of ways to remove this margin on the right of the YouTube Livestream page.
I'm doing this for an extension I'm working on and I'd like the margin to be removed completely from page.

I've already done the following:
`margin: 0px !important;`

It removed the margin on the left side of the page, but there's still a big chunk of margin on the right side and I have no idea how I should remove it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use a browser inspector to identify which element the extra margin is attached to?  Also, are you sure it's `margin` and not `padding`?

Comment: @LHM thanks for your reply. I have used the browser inspector and i've identified that the element is the element with the id: "columns". This element already has the `margin: 0px !important;` attached to it and I'm 100% sure its `margin` because the browser inspector marks `margin` as orange, and that is what the extra space shows up as when I hover over it

Comment: Got a url of an example on a live page over on youtube?

Comment: @Bjorn.B https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_0Jk9CHenI this is the one i used

Answer (score 0):

The other `margin` spacing is actually on the elements directly inside `#columns`, which is `#primary` &  `#secondary`. Overiding those extends width to the window edges.

```
div#columns {
    max-width: 100%!important;
}
div#primary {
    margin: 0!important;
    padding: 0!important;

}
div#secondary {
    padding: 0!important;
}
.html5-video-container video {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: auto!important;
}
```